# Syntax for partial class template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

In the following, am I forgetting some correct syntax for partial specializing class NumInfo or is it even possible to do that?

```
template<typename T>
struct NumInfo {
    T x;
    T y;

    void Print();
};

template<typename T>
void NumInfo <T>::Print() {
    /*.....*/
}

template<typename T>
struct NumInfo <float> {
    T x;
    float y;

    void Print();
};

template<typename T>
void NumInfo <float>::Print() {
    /*.....*/
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your design has a problem -- right now you have multiple classes with the same name `NumInfo<float>` and different definitions (depending on `T`).  To fix that, you'll need a second template parameter, like this:

```
template<typename S, typename T=S>
struct NumInfo
{
    T x;
    S y;

    void Print();
};

template<typename S, typename T>
void NumInfo<S,T>::Print()
{
    /*.....*/
}

template<typename T>
struct NumInfo<float,T>
{
    T x;
    float y;

    void Print();
};

template<typename T>
void NumInfo<float,T>::Print()
{
    /*.....*/
}
```

Comment: I *think* this is the right answer, but it's hard to tell based on the OP's code.

Comment: @JohnDibling: I agree.  It isn't clear whether `x` and `y` are all supposed to be the same type or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T>
struct NumInfo {
    T x;
    T y;

    void Print();
};

template<typename T>
void NumInfo <T>::Print() {
    /*.....*/
}

template<>
struct NumInfo <float> {
    typedef float T;
    T x;
    float y;

    void Print();
};

void NumInfo <float>::Print() {
    /*.....*/
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is OP's intent.  You've just shotgunned away the compiler errors, but haven't addressed the actual problem.