# Specifying one of class template argument value as any

Tags: c++, templates

Consider this class:

```
template<class T, int select>
class Foo()
{
  public:
    Foo() {}
    ~Foo() {}
    Param<select> value;
    void SomeInitialization();
    ...
}
```

Can I partialy specify SomeInitialization() function without explictly mentioning `select` value in it's template parametes list? For example I would like to merge functions realization into single one:

```
template<>
void Foo<SomeClass, 0>::SomeInitialization() { ... }

template<>
void Foo<SomeClass, 1>::SomeInitialization() { ... }

template<>
void Foo<SomeClass, 2>::SomeInitialization() { ... }
```

Into something like this (pseudocode):

```
template<>
void Foo<SomeClass>::SomeInitialization() { ... }
```

where `select` can be any value, since my `SomeInitialization()` function's code doesn't use it anyway and all functions of the above have identical code, but I have to copy paste it for every `select` value.

How can I achieve that? Please provide an answer using example `Foo` class in my post.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7755333/101090), it seems like all you have to do is:

```
template<int N>
void Foo<SomeClass, N>::SomeInitialization() { ... }
```

Comment: Thank for response. But if I do so I get an error when I try to access class members inside this function - "identifier X is undefined". I use MSVS 2012.

Comment: Btw, in the link you provided he just uses float as a type, but I need to know exact value, since my Param<select> constructs parameter based on `select` value, not `select` type